# Intermediate field of $\mathbb F_9(x)/$ $\mathbb F_3(x^2)$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

The title question was a question asked in interview examination in some university.
I want to find all of Intermediate field of $\mathbb F_9(x)/$ $\mathbb F_3(x^2)$.

$\mathbb F_9(x)$＝$\mathbb F_3(x,$$\sqrt{2}$) is OK, but I cannnot proceed from here.
Do I need to rewrite the extension as simple extension?
For the beginning,I cannot specify the extension degree.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You list Galois theory in the tags. Are you familiar with the relationship between the Galois group and intermediate fields? Have you tried computing the Galois group?

Comment: Yes I can use Galois correspondence.I tried to  rewrite the extension into simple extension, and find minimal polynomial.But I cannot find it, so I cannot judge this extension is Galois or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $T^2 - x^2 \in \Bbb F_3(x^2)[T]$ and so $[\Bbb F_3(x) : \Bbb F_3(x^2)] = 2$. On the other hand, we have $\Bbb F_9(x) = \Bbb F_3(\sqrt{2})(x)$ and $T^2-2 \in \Bbb F_3[T] \subset \Bbb F_3(x)[T]$, so $[\Bbb F_9(x) : \Bbb F_3(x)] = 2$.

Thus
$$
[\Bbb F_9(x) : \Bbb F_3(x^2)] = [\Bbb F_9(x) : \Bbb F_3(x)] \cdot [\Bbb F_3(x) \colon \Bbb F_3(x^2)] = 4.
$$

All polynomials considered are separable as we are in characteristic $3$, and the extension is normal because $\Bbb F_9(x) = \Bbb F_3(x^2)(x,\sqrt{2})$ is a splitting field, so the original extension is Galois and

$$
|\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb F_9(x)/\Bbb F_3(x^2))| = 4.
$$

Then $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb F_9(x)/\Bbb F_3(x^2))$ is either the Klein four group of the cyclic group of order $4$, but since any automorphism of $\Bbb F_9(x) = \Bbb F_3(x^2)(x,\sqrt{2})$ is determined by the images of $x$ and $\sqrt{2}$ and those must be roots of their respective minimal polynomials, a direct computation shows that

$$
\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb F_9(x)/\Bbb F_3(x^2)) \simeq \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2.
$$

By the Galois corresponence, intermediate fields correspond to subgroups of the Klein group. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank you very much.! 4th line from the top [F3（x）:F3（x^2）],right?

Comment: @bellow no problem! Glad I could help :) And yes! That was a typo, my bad. Fixed now

Comment: Sorry to bother, but why polynomial in character 3 is separable? And the original extension is not quadratic , why it is normal?

Comment: Both polynomials are irreducible and so they are separable if $f' \neq 0$. But if $f = X^2+b$ then $f' = 2*X$, which is not the zero polynomial unless we are in characteristic $2$.

Comment: @bellow you are right about that second thing. Normality is not implied by both smaller extensions being normal, that can in general fail (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is normal, so is the latter over $\mathbb{Q}$). It's just that the extension is a splitting field for the family $\{T^2-x^2, T^2-2\}$ and so it is normal.